# How to secure wp-content folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I don’t want users to browse and get access to unwanted/other data. So, I want to hide the files from the users. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide all you need to know on how to secure /wp-content and harden a Wordpress installation. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-the-hell-do-i-secure-wp-includes-and-wp-content

Answer (score 2):

That path needs to be exposed for people to view your site.

You could put a blank index.html file in the wp-content directory, but it's not going to change the fact that this directory needs to be accessible for your site to display.

Comment: Wordpress includes a blank `index.php` file by default, but if it's missing, good to add.

Comment: The path needs to be exposed, but it doesn't need to be browsable.